# pam_authenticate return's PAM_MODULE_UNKNOWN ( returns 28 ), how to resolve?

Tags: compiling, arm, pam, cross-compilation, pam-environment

Downloaded the source Linux-PAM-1.3.0.tar.gz version then, configured and compiled using command

`./configure --prefix=/u02/tasks/linux-pam/Linux-PAM-1.3.0/output/pre --exec-prefix=/u02/tasks/linux-pam/Linux-PAM-1.3.0/output/epre CC=/opt/freescale-imx6/usr/local/gcc-4.6.2-glibc-2.13-linaro-multilib-2011.12/fsl-linaro-toolchain/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc ARCH=arm --host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi LDFLAGS="-L/u02/tasks/linux-pam/Linux-PAM-1.3.0/output/epre/lib/ "`

`make install`

then libraries copied to /lib/ and /lib/security/ respectively. In configuration file data is

`auth required pam_unix.so`

`account required pam_unix.so`

In application API's using are

`retval=pam_start("check_user", "root", &conv, &pamh);`

`retval = pam_authenticate(pamh, 0)`

`retval = pam_acct_mgmt(pamh, 0);`

`pam_end(pamh, retval)`

while running application I'm getting the module unknown error.

Comment: did you execute `make install` as root?

Comment: yes. Got the libraries in output/pre and output/epre directories. In libpam/pam_dispatch.c file returns PAM_MODULE_UNKNOWN.